# Complex limit of abs(z)

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Silly question but intuitively and obviously $\lim_{z\to0}|z|$ is $0$, yet it does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations taking $|z|$ to be $u(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y) = 0$, this does not give the required relation for a complex limit to exist. What gives? Should I just treat this and like equations as a real limit if the partial derivatives of complex part $v(x,y)$ are $0$? And likewise of partials of $u$ of $0$ do a real limit on $v$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=|z|$ is continuous, but not differentiable.  There is no issue from the fact $f$ does not satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: *What* is "the required relation for a complex limit to exist"?

Comment: The required relation is: Given the complex function $f(z)$ expressed as $u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ with x and y being the real and imaginary coefficients, that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: This is apparently required for a complex limit to exist, yet a complex function with a constant real or imaginary coefficient will likely not meet this criteria although it may have a limit. So what I am getting at is in those cases do I just do a real limit on the coefficient which does have a derivative and set the other to its constant value? So for example a function with $u(x, y) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ and $v(x, y) = 2$ would have a limit of $\infty+2i$ at $0$?